# Was there mechanicum elements in the Blood Angel legion?

Tags: warhammer-40k, horus-heresy

In the book Signus Daemonicus, 21th book of the Horus Heresy, we follow what I believe is the very first large scale battle between Astartes and Chaos, more specifically Blood Angels against Khorne's army.

However, from what I remember, there is absolutely no mention of any Mechanicum units/machines/elements in the entire book, which seems strange because:

- The (almost) entire Blood Angel legion is gathered in Signus Prime
- Most Astartes Legions have their dedicaded Mechanicum elements and titans (at least so far in the heresy and if I remember well)

Consequently, my question is: **if I remember well and there is in fact no mention of Mechanicum along side the Blood Angels, why is that ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 21st book of the Horus Heresy is *Fear to Tread: The angel falls*. Don't know if the *Signus Daemonicus* is a translation.

> Fear to Tread is the 21st novel in the Horus Heresy Series, written by James Swallow.
>
> From the Lexicanum [article on Fear To Tread](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Fear_to_Tread_(Novel))

But as the story matches with what you mentioned and the plot location is the Signus System, I assume we speak about the same book.

The goal of the deployment was to get rid of the flaw in their Geneseed, the Red Thirst.

> A small envoy of Word Bearers led by Apostle Tanus Kreed arrive in-system bearing new orders for Sanguinius from Horus. The reason for the unconventional communication is made clear when a female astropath the envoys brought with them acts as a conduit between Sanguinius and Horus, allowing them to converse directly as if they were in the same room. Horus reveals to Sanguinius that the nephilim have survived and taken over a distant star system in the Northern Cross, specifically a group of planets and suns called the Signus Cluster. He tasks the Blood Angels with destroying them and when Sanguinius questions why they are being given a campaign suited to a more brutal Legion Horus tells him *that the nephilim have a technology that can counteract the Red Thirst*. Sanguinius agrees to crush the nephilim for good.
>
> From the Lexicanum [article on Fear To Tread](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Fear_to_Tread_(Novel))

This flaw was (and still is) kept a secret from everybody outside the legion and chapter, as can be read in the prologue. Mechanicum weapons used by the legions are heavy weapons as Titans and similar ways to destroy whole cities with a single blast. That is not the goal of the legion, they'd way more likely prefer to have the planet sacked without anything being destroyed in order to find the technology to counteract the Red Thirst.

Furthermore, they'd like to keep this a secret. An adept of the Mechanicum joining them in the exploration of the city and observing them (or some Techmarines) analyzing the Nephilim technology would lead to some uncomfortable questions being asked. This is reinforced by, IIRC, the fact that no human auxiliary is with them, i.e. there are no non-Blood Angel combatants on the field at all.

The last thing I see, why they aren't mentioned, is that they're not relevant. This book dwells into the Blood Angels and the Red Thirst, their fight against the daemons and so on. Adding the Mechanicum to the story would IMO not add anything to the story. It's the same with the Fall of Prospero. The Space Wolves attack a planet defended by the Thousand Sons, they fight heavily, the Sisters of Silence are mentioned as shield against the Psykers but no Mechanicum or Army support, although this would've probably also be used. It's simply not relevant for the story.

Comment: *Signus Daemonicus* is the title of *Fear to Tread* in France.

Comment: @Taladris Indeed. As it is latin, I thought it would be the name for all the languages, which is obviously wrong.